# ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up bridge

Tags: virtual-machine, openflow, sdn, opendaylight, openvswitch

I have set up OVS on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM (https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and am trying to add a bridge and port to the same. But it keeps throwing out this error and does not get added. Has anyone faced anything similar ? Screenshot of error attached.

[OVS-VSCTL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBKUQ.png)

I have already got my ODL controller ready on the same VM and need to get the bridge and port up on OVS to connect to it.

Thanks

Comment: 1. What's in ovs-vswitchd log? Could you replace "Openflow" in the add-br command for "br0"? 3. Could you downgrade to OVS 2.4.0 and try again?

Comment: I have the same error and my ovs-vswitchd log is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved when I used the netdev datapath type:

"-- set bridge br0 datapath_type=netdev".

Thanks,
Monica

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Don't knwo what to do.